# Downloading WATCH Data: http response code 500

Tags: qgis, http

I am not a professional and doing some qgis tutorials on SUEWS, WUDAPT and WATCH. I don't know if I am allowed to post links so: The tutorial is from the UMEP website.

Now I am stuck at downloading meteorological data, because I get the Error:

> Data download not completed: Error connecting to server. Got HTTP response code 500

I am able to open WATCH, thats not the problem, because I installed pandas and I was able to use the Spatial downloader for population density. It's not like I can't download anything...but now I do need the meteorological data input to go on with SUEWS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Kaymahn, welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! I think it is very importing to give us more information, including links and the minimal code to reproduce the problem. You may want to read the [guideline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: 500 status code, is an Internal Server Error, there is nothing on your side you can do as there is an issue with the server receiving or sending information.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is now replaced with a ERA5 downloaded. Try this instead.
https://umep-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pre-processor/Meteorological%20Data%20Download%20data%20(ERA5).html